# How manage a API (DeepL) which send data in UTF-8 format?

Tags: python, api, utf-8, python-requests, deepl

I use the DeepL API : https://www.deepl.com/docs-api/translating-text/

I interact with it by using *python* and *request* library.

```
import requests
import ast
r =  requests.post(url='https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate',
                   data = {
                        'target_lang' : 'FR',  
                        'auth_key' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        'text': ''Honey Was ist denn los hier?''})
print(ast.literal_eval(r.text)['translations'][0]['text'])
```

Output :

> > 'ChÃ©rie, que se passe-t-il ici ?'

As you see i get 'ChÃ©rie' instead of 'Chérie'

And it's normal because the DeepL API :
"Only UTF8-encoded plain text is supported."

But i have no idea to get a correct text (here 'Chérie'), i try some tools like '.encode('utf-8')' in the input but it does'nt work.

Have you an idea ? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your terminal probably thinks that the output is Latin-1 (or CP1252), while it's actually UTF-8. You can test with `print('Ch\u00E9rie')`.

Comment: But maybe it's also caused by the fact that you're using an interesting approach to en-/decoding JSON. Why not `requests.post(..., json={'target_lang': ...})`, followed by `r.json()` for deserialising the response?

Comment: Oh it works ! Thanks :)
I used :
import requests
import ast
r =  requests.post(url='https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate',
                          data = {
                            'target_lang' : 'FR',  
                            'auth_key' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'',
                            'text': 'Honey Was it denn los hier?'})
r.json()['translations'][0]['text']

And i get >> 'Chérie, que se passe-t-il ici ?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used :

```
import requests 
import ast 
r = requests.post(url='api.deepl.com/v2/translate', 
      data = { 'target_lang' : 'FR', 
               'auth_key' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
               'text': 'Honey Was it denn los hier?'}) 

print(r.json()['translations'][0]['text'])
```

And i get :

> > 'Chérie, que se passe-t-il ici ?

Thanks lenz ;)

Comment: Why don't you send the payload with the `json=` parameter?

Comment: It works without, are they a additional advantage ?

Comment: Oh I'm wrong I guess. With `data=`, the payload is being form-encoded, which is apparently what the API expects. I'm just so used to sending payloads as JSON in a POST request.